# How to check if url is protected or not in TomEE?

Tags: java, security, tomcat, apache-tomee

I'm trying to implement JWT based authentication in TomEE 8 (based on Tomcat 9).
I use org.glassfish.soteria:jakarta.security.enterprise:1.0.1 as an implementation of Jakarta Security.
Following this tutorial [https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/blob/master/javaee/security-jwt-example/src/main/java/fish/payara/examples/security/JWTAuthenticationMechanism.java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_impl_securejaxrs_annotations.html) java class looks like this:

```
@RequestScoped 
public class JWTAuthenticationMechanism implements HttpAuthenticationMechanism 

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationMechanism.class.getName());

/**
 * Access to the
 * IdentityStore(AuthenticationIdentityStore,AuthorizationIdentityStore) is
 * abstracted by the IdentityStoreHandler to allow for multiple identity
 * stores to logically act as a single IdentityStore
 */
@Inject
private IdentityStoreHandler identityStoreHandler;

@Inject
private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

@Override
public AuthenticationStatus validateRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpMessageContext context) {

    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "validateRequest: {0}", request.getRequestURI());
    // Get the (caller) name and password from the request
    // NOTE: This is for the smallest possible example only. In practice
    // putting the password in a request query parameter is highly insecure
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String token = extractToken(context);

    if (name != null && password != null) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "credentials : {0}, {1}", new String[]{name, password});
        // validation of the credential using the identity store
        CredentialValidationResult result = identityStoreHandler.validate(new UsernamePasswordCredential(name, password));
        if (result.getStatus() == CredentialValidationResult.Status.VALID) {
            // Communicate the details of the authenticated user to the container and return SUCCESS.
            return createToken(result, context);
        }
        // if the authentication failed, we return the unauthorized status in the http response
        return context.responseUnauthorized();
    } else if (token != null) {
        // validation of the jwt credential
        return validateToken(token, context);
    } else if (context.isProtected()) {
        // A protected resource is a resource for which a constraint has been defined.
        // if there are no credentials and the resource is protected, we response with unauthorized status
        return context.responseUnauthorized();
    }
    // there are no credentials AND the resource is not protected, 
    // SO Instructs the container to "do nothing"
    return context.doNothing();
}
...
```

User sends login request with username and password, identityStoreHandler validates it. Then we generate JWT token and send it back. Frontend attaches it to each next request.
This works.
validateRequest() is triggered for every request, protected or unprotected. As I understand it comes from the spec and is a desired behaviour.
Now, if token is expired and user sends request to not protected url - it will be rejected, because token is present and invalid.
I want first to check if url is protected or not and only if it's protected check for token presence and validity. But ((HttpMessageContext ) context.isProtected()) always returns false. In controller protected methods are annotated with @RolesAllowed and @PermitAll annotations. I tried this also with web.xml based constraints, but isProtected() is still false.
Why is it always false?

Update
I was under the wrong impression that annotation-based security and via descriptor (web.xml) are interchangeable.
If web.xml doesn't contain any security constraints - requests of unauthenticated user to resources with @RolesAllowed are rejected with 403 error, requests to resources with @PermitAll are fulfilled. This is strange behaviour, both require authenticated user and should be rejected.
If web.xml has auth-constraint tag then context.isProtected() returns true for that url-pattern.
But it still returns false for methods annotated with @RolesAllowed and @PermitAll, if path in those methods doesn't match url-pattern in web.xml.
According to this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_impl_securejaxrs_annotations.html

> Annotated constraints are additional to any configured security constraints. The JAX-RS runtime environment checks for annotated constraints after the web container runtime environment has checked for security constraints that are configured in the web.xml file.

Does it mean that container based security (Soteria) will not consider annotated methods as protected?